# How do I express a :has_one assocation :through a collection, with a :condition to construct/select "the one"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've got some models (Rails 3.2) like this, A->B->C, to model a Manager (A) who covers many Areas (B), each of which has many Addresses (C).  One of those addresses is the manager's primary address.  I can't figure out the best way to associate a Manager with his primary address.

```
class AreaManager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :areas, :dependent=>:destroy
  has_many :addresses, :through=>:areas
  ...
  def primary_address
    self.addresses.where(:primary=>true).first 
      # in fact, there can be only one
  end
end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area_manager
  has_many :addresses,:dependent=>:destroy
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area
  attr_accessible :primary 
    # this is the manager's primary address (not the area's)
end
```

This allows me to say, for example:

```
a = AreaManager.find(123)
a.primary_address # => her primary address
```

But what I really want is a constructor/setter as well as a getter:

```
a = AreaManager.new
a.build_primary_address ...
```

I can add to Area:

```
has_one :primary_address, 
  :class_name=>'Address', 
  :conditions => {:primary=>true}
```

and this allows me to do

```
a1 = Area.new
a1.build_primary_address ... # instantiates an Address with primary = true
```

but when I try to do something similar to AreaManager, by adding

```
has_one :primary_address, 
  :through=>:areas, 
  :source=>:address, 
  :conditions=>{:primary=>true}
```

and then say:

```
a = AreaManager.new
a.build_primary_address ... 
  # instead of creating an area and an address, it croaks
```

I get a ActiveRecord::HasOneThroughCantAssociateThroughCollection exception.  I can't figure out what the right incantation might be (or if there is one).  Is there a Railsy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As rails is all about following conventions and the right chocie from many options, I would recommend:

- Don't apply conditions to an association
- Look to use a named `scope`
- Look to use `.where` (rails3) instead of `conditions` (rails2).  See the [ActiveRecord api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) for more
  Applying all this will likely change your code a fair bit and you'll get different results.